# How to test the reception of Broadcast Receivers?

Tags: android, testing, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing tests to verify the reception of the transmitting receivers but for some reason, the receiver is never registered or the intent is never sent.

I guess there should be a problem with the Context but, no luck yet finding it.

This is the BroadcastFactory.kt:

```
object BroadcastFactory {

    private lateinit var intent: Intent

    fun build(
        action: String,
        flag: Int? = null,
    ): BroadcastFactory {
        intent = Intent().apply {
            this.action = action
            this.flags = flag ?: 0
        }
        return this
    }

    fun send(
        context: Context
    ): Intent {
        context.sendBroadcast(intent)
        return intent
    }
}
```

And this is the test file BroadcastTest.kt:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class BroadcastTest {

    lateinit var intents: MutableList<Intent>
    lateinit var latch: CountDownLatch
    private lateinit var receiver: BroadcastReceiverTester

    inner class BroadcastReceiverTester : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            intent?.let {
                intents.add(it)
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }
    }

    private val context: Context = getInstrumentation().targetContext

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        intents = mutableListOf()
        latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        receiver = BroadcastReceiverTester()

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
            receiver,
            IntentFilter.create(
                Constants.ACTION, "text/plain"
            )
        )

    }

    @Test
    fun testBroadcastReception() {
        BroadcastFactory
            .build(Constants.ACTION, Constants.FLAG)
            .send(context)

        // assert broadcast reception (NOT WORKING)
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        assertThat(intents.size).isEqualTo(1)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }

}
```

I'm using a CountDownLatch to wait 10 seconds for the receiver, plus, its value can be asserted. Besides, I set a list of Intents to check the number of registrations/receptions.

There is something I'm missing here? Different context provider? Robolectric runner?

Thanks

Comment: You're conflating two separate mechanisms. `LocalBroadcastManager` is completely separate from `Context` broadcasts, and they do not work together. Assuming you mean to be testing the platform `Context` broadcasts (since `LocalBroadcastManager` is extremely deprecated) you need to call `registerReceiver()` on the `Context` instead.

Comment: Are you testing if `LocalBroadcastManager` works or `context.sendBroadcast`  or your code? (first 2 items are tested already) if you wana test `BroadcastFactory` then checking intent returned from send should be enough ...

Comment: I already tried that @MikeM. and got the same result. Plus, it seems the deprecated class is for Java only, kotlin equivalent is stable.

Comment: No, it's deprecated everywhere. The component itself is deprecated; the language doesn't matter. That's rather irrelevant, though, 'cause it's still not going to work with `context.sendBroadcast()`.

Comment: @Selvin I have a system of multiple apps that send multiple broadcasts between them, and I thought to isolate the creation in a factory and the reception in an interface for all the receivers is a good idea.

So I'm preparing this environment with these tests, I know I can trust in the broadcasting behaviour of the framework, but I don't trust in my systems broadcasts so I want to test all of them through this suite. I'm I wrong?

Comment: I just noticed, too, that your broadcast doesn't match the `IntentFilter`. You're filtering for a `"text/plain"` data type, but the broadcast `Intent` doesn't have any data set on it.

Comment: That was set because the real example does have data. But.. you actually got the real issue here, I got the test done changing the IntentFilter as:

```
 IntentFilter(
                Constants.ACTION
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is solved it by changing the receiver with this:

```
context.registerReceiver(
            receiver,
            IntentFilter(
                Constants.ACTION
            )
        )
```

Thanks to @selvin and @mike-m for the help!